JWT Token Expiration Handling Issue in Express.js Middleware
I'm having a problem with my Express server and frontend communication. I have created an auth middleware that verifies the JWT token, which I've already stored inside a cookie. The problem occurs when the token inside the cookie expires. When it does, I send a 401 response and a JSON message that looks like this:

            return res.status(401).json({ message: 'JWT expired', code: 'TOKEN_EXPIRED', redirectTo: '/login' });

When the JWT token stored in the cookie expires, my middleware correctly sends a 401 response, but the frontend doesn't handle it as expected. I want to ensure that the expired token triggers the correct response on the frontend.
However the server rejects requests to the protected route because the middleware is blocking access and only returns a JSON response to the client. I have tried making a fetch request to the URL, but no matter what code I write on the client side to intercept the server's response, the server still refuses the connection leaving me with only the server's JSON response on the client/page.
Here is the fetch request I'm using:
const checkToken = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/admin/register', {
                    method: 'GET',
                    credentials: 'include' 
                });
                if(!response.ok){
                    console.log(10)

                }
                if (!response.ok || response.status === 403 || response.status === 401) {
                    const data = await response.json();
                    if (data.code === 'TOKEN_EXPIRED') {
                        // Redirect to login page if the token has expired
                        window.location.href = data.redirectTo;
                    } else {
              
                        console.error('Error:', data.message || 'Unknown error');
) 
/* but that doesnt go through iam getting request forbidden from the client 
   the server authmiddleware is like This*/ 

jwt.verify(token, JWT_SECRET, (err, decoded) => {
        if (err) {
            if (err.name === 'TokenExpiredError') {
                req.isTokenExpired = true
                console.error('JWT expired:', err);
                return res.status(401).json({ message: 'JWT expired', code: 'TOKEN_EXPIRED', redirectTo: '/login' });

            }
            console.error('JWT verification failed:', err);
            return res.status(401).json({ message: 'JWT verification failed', code: 'TOKEN_INVALID' });
        })

